# Unable to fork personal github repository

Tags: github

I have a github repository in my personal git account that I want to fork. It is a private git repo and only I can access it. But the Fork button at the top right of the page is greyed out and I cannot find the option to enable it in settings.

According to the [documentation on git](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/managing-repository-settings/managing-the-forking-policy-for-your-repository), the option should be under 'Features' in the repo settings, but the 'Features' section in my git repo has no option related to forking (screenshot below). The documentation also is talking about organizations etc, but my account is not associated with any organization, it's a personal account. Please tell me how to fork?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1.**In the top right corner of GitHub.com, click your profile photo, then click Your organizations**.

[image]

2.**Next to the organization, click Settings.**
[image]

3.**In the left sidebar, click Member privileges**.
[image]

4.**Under "Repository forking", select Allow forking of private repositories or Allow forking of private and internal repositories**.
[image]

5.**Click Save**

`or`

if there is no organization linked to your account then try to lfollow these steps:-

```
 1. clone the private repository
 2. make a branch
 3. work on the branch
 4. push the branch to the private repository
 5. goto GitHub and create a pull request from the branch on the private repository
 6. someone else reviews the the pull request and decides to merge it with master on GitHub
 7. delete the branch unless there was a problem and it was not merged then go back to #3
```

Comment: There is no "Your Organizations" option in that drop-down for me, probably because there are no organizations linked to my account.

Comment: i done some edits, see if this helps

Answer (score 1):

The fork option is not available within the settings, because your repo is private and not hosted by an organization (instead your personal account). According to my information, you can not fork your own repository, therefore your fork button is grayed out, because - as you have mentioned - your personal account is not part of any kind of organization, which can be selected as the target hosting account of the fork.

I have found this gist which will maybe help you to "fork" it manually:
https://gist.github.com/0xjac/85097472043b697ab57ba1b1c7530274